# Is it possible to bind Content Assist to the Windows/Meta key in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'd like to bind Content Assist to the Meta key, because pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> each time is not really convenient. I've tried to do it through preferences, but pressing the Meta key does nothing. Is it even possible to do this?